# Telerik RadGrid Overflow

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, telerik, radgrid

There are so many columns on my Telerik RadGrid that I want to make it horizontally scrollable. Please help me. Thank everyone. I'm using VS 2010, my web runs on FireFox and IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by using Frozen Column Functionality.

please check below link for demo.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/frozencolumns/defaultcs.aspx